# What is the latest on Microsoft Expression Studio licensing?

Tags: microsoft-expression

In the past, there's been an issue with Microsoft not allowing you to deactivate an Expression Studio key. Basically, you get two keys per license. If you assign both keys (say one to a desktop and one to a laptop), then you upgrade to a new machine (say you replace your laptop or upgrade some of the hardware), you have to buy a new copy of Expression Studio ($600 for Ultimate). This seems ludicrous to me, and I'm wondering if anyone knows if this policy is still in place. I can't seem to find a EULA online anywhere, so I don't know where to find this information. I know my laptop is due for replacement soon, and I want to know if I'm going to have to sink $600 into a software product I already purchased.

For background, please refer to this thread on the Microsoft Expression forums:
http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/general/thread/da5587bc-b098-4c6a-9a56-af3608d940d0

Note that this thread is locked. Microsoft doesn't seem to want people to discuss this. This is one reason I'm posting here rather than on that site.

Comment: I would contact Microsoft before you upgrade your system. They may be able to help you out by giving you another license or monitoring the usage of the license and let you install the license on another computer.

Comment: @David, I have spent many hours on the phone with Microsoft in the past regarding this issue. I don't have time right now to go through that again, but I thought maybe someone could provide some more recent data.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to help @DanM. That is honestly the only way I have ever been able to do that.

Comment: @David, I didn't mean to sound ungrateful for your comment. It's just very frustrating to deal with customer service people who don't know what they're talking about and send you all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if you are unable to activate online, call the Phone Activation call center. After the IVR activation fails, you will be transferred to a representative. I have never been denied after telling them that I got a new machine and need an activation code.

Comment: This is exactly what was discussed in the questions comments already. Good suggestion though. This is exactly what I said. :)

Comment: Please read the thread I linked to. Expression Studio doesn't work like other Microsoft products (e.g., Office). What you're suggesting has already been tried many times. I'm looking for new information from people who have attempted to deactivate (or transfer) an Expression Studio key in the last couple months.